# Setting Values with pandas DataFrame.loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider I have a data frame :

```
>>> data
   c0  c1  c2   _c1   _c2
0   0   1   2  18.0  19.0
1   3   4   5   NaN   NaN
2   6   7   8  20.0  21.0
3   9  10  11   NaN   NaN
4  12  13  14   NaN   NaN
5  15  16  17   NaN   NaN
```

I want to update the values in the c1 and c2 columns with the values in the _c1 and _c2 columns whenever those latter values are not `NaN`. Why won't the following work, and what is the correct way to do this?

```
>>> data.loc[~(data._c1.isna()),['c1','c2']]=data.loc[~(data._c1.isna()),['_c1','_c2']]
>>> data
   c0    c1    c2   _c1   _c2
0   0   NaN   NaN  18.0  19.0
1   3   4.0   5.0   NaN   NaN
2   6   NaN   NaN  20.0  21.0
3   9  10.0  11.0   NaN   NaN
4  12  13.0  14.0   NaN   NaN
5  15  16.0  17.0   NaN   NaN
```

For completeness's sake I want the result to look like

```
>>> data.loc[~(data._c1.isna()),['c1','c2']]=data.loc[~(data._c1.isna()),['_c1','_c2']]
>>> data
   c0    c1    c2   _c1   _c2
0   0  18.0  19.0. 18.0  19.0
1   3   4.0   5.0   NaN   NaN
2   6  20.0  21.0  20.0  21.0
3   9  10.0  11.0   NaN   NaN
4  12  13.0  14.0   NaN   NaN
5  15  16.0  17.0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Prefer use `data._c1.notna()` rather than `~(data._c1.isna())` for readability.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Corralien I'll make sure to change that in my code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend `update` after `rename`

```
df.update(df[['_c1','_c2']].rename(columns={'_c1':'c1','_c2':'c2'}))
df
Out[266]: 
   c0    c1    c2   _c1   _c2
0   0  18.0  19.0  18.0  19.0
1   3   4.0   5.0   NaN   NaN
2   6  20.0  21.0  20.0  21.0
3   9  10.0  11.0   NaN   NaN
4  12  13.0  14.0   NaN   NaN
5  15  16.0  17.0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't even know that df.update was a thing. I'll use that a lot more now I think. Do you by any chance know WHY the above doesn't work like I thought it would?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df[['c1', 'c2']] = np.where(df[['_c1', '_c2']].notna(),
                            df[['_c1', '_c2']],
                            df[['c1', 'c2']])
print(df)

# Output:
   c0    c1    c2   _c1   _c2
0   0  18.0  19.0  18.0  19.0
1   3   4.0   5.0   NaN   NaN
2   6  20.0  21.0  20.0  21.0
3   9  10.0  11.0   NaN   NaN
4  12  13.0  14.0   NaN   NaN
5  15  16.0  17.0   NaN   NaN
```

**Update**

> Do you know by any chance WHY the above doesn't work the way I thought it would?

Your column names from left and right side of your expression are different so Pandas can't use this values even if the shape is the same.

```
# Left side of your expression
>>> data.loc[~(data._c1.isna()),['c1','c2']]
     c1    c2  # <- note the column names
0  18.0  19.0
2  20.0  21.0

# Right side of your expression
>>> data.loc[~(data._c1.isna()),['_c1','_c2']]
    _c1   _c2  # <- Your column names are difference from left side
0  18.0  19.0
2  20.0  21.0
```

How to solve it? Simply use `.values` on the right side. As your right side is not row/column indexed, Pandas use the shape to set the values.

```
data.loc[~(data._c1.isna()),['c1','c2']] = \
    data.loc[~(data._c1.isna()),['_c1','_c2']].values
print(data)

# Output:
   c0    c1    c2   _c1   _c2
0   0  18.0  19.0  18.0  19.0
1   3   4.0   5.0   NaN   NaN
2   6  20.0  21.0  20.0  21.0
3   9  10.0  11.0   NaN   NaN
4  12  13.0  14.0   NaN   NaN
5  15  16.0  17.0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is also a good and efficient answer but BENY got their answer in a little bit quicker than you. I'm using this elsewhere in my codebase because it's fast and effective and I'm kind of embarrassed I didn't think of it since I do know how to use np.where. Do you know by any chance WHY the above doesn't work the way I thought it would?

Comment: No word on WHY the above doesn't work though? :D

Comment: You updated your comment, no? What's wrong. Do you have an error?

Comment: No I just don't understand why my original solution doesn't work. Your solution is definitely correct, I just don't see why my original solution isn't.

Comment: I definitely have the right answer, lol :). Do you understand my explanation (English is not my best skill :-P)

Comment: Yeah, you definitely have an acceptable answer. I'm just wondering why this `data.loc[~(data._c1.isna()),['c1','c2']]=data.loc[~(data._c1.isna()),['_c1','_c2']]` is not also correct.

Comment: Do you miss my updated answer?

Comment: Yes I did miss that. Thanks for the explanation!